# Error after changing folder Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I moved website to root but now always my website.com redirect me to website.com/folder/ 
I have change ps_configuration link and ssl, change ps_shop_url with `/` for virtual url but not working

The problem is from prestashop not my dns because if i change index.php by a simple echo its work good

I have already clear smarty cache and browser cache

In my htaccess i have the original with

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]
```

What is the solution for disabled this redirection plz ? Thanks

Comment: what `folder` it is redirecting to. did you previously installed it in that `folder`. can u provide your site's link, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for reply its work i just forget to empty cloudflare cache ...